# Upgrade from Windows 7 (64-bit) to Windows 8 change to 32-bit version. How to get it to 64-bit version?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1

I had the 64-bit version of the OS while I had Windows 7 in my laptop but when I upgraded it to Windows 8 it became the 32-bit version. How did that happen? And now my RAM has decreased. How can I get Windows 8 to be 64-bit?

Comment: Great Question!! You have an 64 bit cpu. The former windows 7 was a 64 bit version. Now you have a 32 bit version of windows 8 installed. You have to install a 64 bit version of windows 8 to get the bits back and use all the memory.

Comment: You use the term "upgraded" but what you actually did is performed a "clean install" of Windows 8.  If you had performed an "upgrade" installation you would still have a 64-bit installation of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do a clean install of a 64bit version of Windows 8.1. Don't forget to take a back-up of your important files, documents, etc first.

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: Correct. You cannot do an in-place upgrade of architectures. The only solution is a wipe and re-install.